# Getting connected/disconnected status from Chromecast Audio using PyChromecast

Tags: python, chromecast

I'm trying to write a script to sense whether either of my two CC audios are disconnected, and if so, do some other stuff. I have tried a few different approaches, such as pinging the devices. The problem is, I can ping them even when I am unable to connect to them through Google Home.

So, I am trying to use `PyChromecast`. I've tried a few different functions within `PyChromecast`. The simplest one should be the one I have quoted below. However, I always get None, whether it's connected or not.

```
def chromcastTest():
    castGarage = pychromecast.Chromecast("192.xxx.x.xx")
    print(castGarage.status)
```

Output:

> None

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the chromecasts in the area with:

```
chromecasts = pychromecast.get_chromecasts()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it in SocketClient object:

```py
def chromcastTest():
  castGarage = pychromecast.Chromecast("192.xxx.x.xx")
  print(castGarage.socket_client.is_connected)
```